# Delete a sorted groupe of Todos from my rest api database (JSON)

Tags: reactjs

I have added a Rest API database to my React Todo app.

I would like to delete a group from my database with the parameter: done=true. Is it not possible to do this simply with the command

```
const handleClearTodos = async() => {
        
        const { status } = await axios.delete(endpoint + '/todos?done=true');
        fetchTodos();
        
}
```

I alwas got the Error: DELETE /todos?done=true 404

I can create, show and delete single todos, but this command does not work for whole groups.

Comment: are you handling that parameter in your backend with the `DELETE` method?

Comment: yes, I created a fake Rest API via: npm json-server.

Comment: 404 suggests the server does not have a path/route configured that matches the one you are trying to request.
REST APIs commonly have DELETE configured like this: /{resource}/{id} to delete a specific item in that resource.
But if you have created a new functionality in your resource controller (on the server) to cater the request, try and share that for more clarity.